# Could not find sub module [portal-service-ejb-1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar] as defined in application.xml

Tags: maven, netbeans, deployment, glassfish, glassfish-3

I am using maven and NetBeans. I was able to deploy and run my application. But now it throws an error:

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [portal-ear-1.4-SNAPSHOT] : Could not find sub module [portal-service-ejb-1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar] as defined in application.xml.

When I go to target/portal-ear-1.4-SNAPSHOT I can see portal-service-ejb-1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar But still it throws me this error.

My application.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
  <display-name>e2e-portal-ear</display-name>
      <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>portal-war-1.4-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/portal</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>portal-repository-ejb-1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>portal-service-ejb-1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
  </module>
     <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I resolved this bug.

So it was a file in `C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\portal-ear-1.4-SNAPSHOT`

There was a file here. Which I think it saves the state of the application or something. I just removed it and everything now works fine.